# Pamac error - Failed to prepare transaction: invalid or corrupted database

Tags: software-installation, manjaro, vlc

I was trying to install VLC in my linux manjaro , but when i do pamac update this happens -

```
pamac update
Warning: Building packages as dynamic user
Warning: Setting build directory to /var/cache/pamac
Preparing...
Synchronizing package databases...
Refreshing core.db...                                                                                               
Refreshing extra.db...                                                                                              
Refreshing community.db...                                                                                          
Refreshing multilib.db...                                                                                           
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data                                                                            
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature)
Failed to synchronize databases
Refreshing AUR...                                                                                                   
Checking google-chrome dependencies...                                                                              
Error: Failed to prepare transaction: invalid or corrupted database

Edit build files : [e] 
Apply transaction ? [e/y/N] y

Transaction cancelled.
[Saksham-Sahgal saksham]# pamac install vlc
Preparing...
Synchronizing package databases...
Refreshing core.db...                                                                                               
Refreshing extra.db...                                                                                              
Refreshing community.db...                                                                                          
Refreshing multilib.db...                                                                                           
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data                                                                            
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
Error: multilib.db: GPGME error: No data
invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature)
Failed to synchronize databases
```

where am I going wrong?

```
Choose optional dependencies for vlc:
 1:  vcdimager: navigate VCD with libvcdinfo
 2:  gnu-free-fonts: subtitle font
 3:  libnfs: NFS access
 4:  protobuf: chromecast streaming
 5:  lua52-socket: http interface
 6:  libtiger: Tiger rendering for Kate streams
 7:  sdl_image: SDL image support
 8:  lirc: lirc control
 9:  libgoom2: Goom visualization
10:  projectm: ProjectM visualisation
11:  aribb24: aribsub support
12:  aribb25: aribcam support

Enter a selection (default=none): 1-12        

Checking google-chrome dependencies...
Error: Failed to prepare transaction: target not found: aribb25
Error: Failed to prepare transaction: invalid or corrupted database
```

Comment: Looks to me like you might be using a bad mirror. See e.g., [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pacman-mirrors). Try updating your mirrors and then run `pacman -Syy` to refresh your repo databases.

Comment: it worked thanks!